# Add an integer to variable value

Tags: javascript

I want to add 52 to the value of a variable I have.

So in principle:

```
Var chicken = eggs+52
```

Eggs being 100, so chicken then becomes 152...

Current method is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use **`.parseInt()`** in Javascript

```
var chicken = parseInt(eggs, 10) + 52;
```

Comment: `Var` V as Upper Case is a typo.

Comment: Thanks  Subir Kumar Sao

Comment: This might not be the issue, the first problem is the syntax error `Var`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. `Var` should be `var` because JavaScript is case sensitive.

Also you might need to cast `eggs` as a number, if it is currently a string:

```
var chicken = +eggs + 52; // the +eggs casts as a number
```

Remember to check the developer console (F12) when debugging, because usually there is an error pointing to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `eggs` is not a type of Number.

You can parse it like,

`var chicken = parseInt(eggs,10)+52;`